# Should you use belongs_to if belonging to the object is optional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How does that work if you have, say, a post object (user can make posts) and it may or may not belong to something else (like a category)? Basically I want the user to still be able to post things, but they can categorize them if they want. If I put that the post belongs_to category, then I feel like if would have to be that way or it will throw an error. How do I do this if it's optional?

Comment: suppose the first Post doesn't have a category, then Post.first.category will return nil... indicating that there's no related Category. This only throws an error if you are trying to call methods on that object.. so you should check if there's a category like this: `Post.first.category.name if Post.first.category.present?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you put something like following validation at your post, it won't throw an error:

```
validates :category, presence: true # it ensures that category must be present
```

simply the `category_id` will be nil at that post entity where category is not present, there is nothing wrong about it. If there were 10s and 100s of redundant columns then I think it would be better to go for [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It was confusing to me how that would work. Perfect answer.

Comment: But implementing this makes a Category mandatory (and checks that the specified Category actually exists in the DB)... you should determine if that is functionality you want.

Answer (score 1):

`belongs_to` just tells Rails that there could be a related record in the database. It's completely optional. If the user doesn't choose a Category, then Rails will save category_id = nil and there's no category for the specific Post. Just like you said it should work.

Only make sure that when displaying the Category that the `@post.category` object will not contain an AcitveRecord object and you cannot call any methods on it like `@post.category.name`, if you do that it will throw a 'no method for nill' error.

If you would like to display the Category name you should do it like this:

```
@post.category.name if @post.category.present?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can handle this situation in a better way by adding a scope for `has_many` association for `Post`s in your `Category` model:

```
  class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :posts, -> { where 'category_id IS NOT NULL' }
  end

  class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
  end
```

In your `Category` model, you can **conditionally** add the `has_many` association for `Post`s as shown above. That way, you can avoid posts from the association that don't belong to the category i.e. `category_id` is `nil`.

See the [Rails documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many) for more information.

Comment: This is already infered... since when a Post does not have a category_id set, it's not related to Category. So Category.first.posts only contains posts for which the category_id = 1 (if that is that first record in the categories table has id=1 of course)